# How to change background color of a table cell or row in a visual basic asp.net web application program

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

In a Visual Basic WEB APPLICATION program that shows 2 column, multi-row table with questions down the left column, and answers down the right column, how can I set the background color of a specific cell OR an entire row?   (that's how I'll indicate selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:gray;">Question 1</td>
                <td>Answer 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Question 2</td>
                <td>Answer 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:yellow;">
                <td>Question 3</td>
                <td>Answer 4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```